# How to get the id of last insert in nextjs/supabase

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-js

With my current project i'm using supabase and nextjs. Something weird is occurring, after inserting a row into a table i want to get the id of said row, but it does not work and i have no idea why.

```
import { supabase } from '../utils/supabaseClient';

export default function TestSupabase() {
    const testSupabaseConnection = async () => {
        try {
            const { data, error } = await supabase
                .from('your_table')
                .insert([{ column1: 'value1', column2: 'value2' }]);
            
            console.log('Data:', data, 'Error:', error);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Unexpected Error:', err);
        }
    };
    

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Supabase Konfigurationstest</h1>
            <button onClick={testSupabaseConnection}>Teste Supabase-Verbindung</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
// utils/supabaseClient.js
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const supabaseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL;
const supabaseKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;
export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);
```

```
{
  "name": "goatlib",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ericblade/quagga2": "^1.8.4",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.2",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

console Output is: `Data: null Error: null` although the row is inserted always. The code above is basically out of the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your query you need to add select like this:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
.from('your_table')
.insert([{ column1: 'value1', column2: 'value2' }])
.select();
```

If you just want the id you can include it in your select braket

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, actually i was sure i already tried this

Answer (score 0):

To be able to achieve this you are going to have to use the `select()` and `single()` method

```
import { supabase } from '../utils/supabaseClient';

export default function TestSupabase() {
    const testSupabaseConnection = async () => {
        try {
            const { data, error } = await supabase
                .from('your_table')
                .insert([{ column1: 'value1', column2: 'value2' }])
                .single("id") // specify the column you want returned
                .single();

            
            console.log('Data:', data, 'Error:', error);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Unexpected Error:', err);
        }
    };
    

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Supabase Konfigurationstest</h1>
            <button onClick={testSupabaseConnection}>Teste Supabase-Verbindung</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: single did not help, but select!